# Где правильно хранить файлы в WPF приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf, безопасность

Добрый день, 
У меня такой вопрос, где и как правильно хранить файлы в WPF приложении, но так что бы доступ к файлам был только программно, из вне что бы до директории достучаться нельзя было ?

Comment: Напишите подробнее какие файлы вам необходимо хранить. И что вы подразумеваете под "из вне что бы до директории достучаться нельзя было". Как вариант делать файлы скрытыми/сериализовать/шифровать по отдельности или все вместе

Comment: Дать доступ до файлов только определенной учётной записи. С данными из файлов работать через специальный сервис, который работает под той самой определённой учётной записью. В простейшем случае файлы можно открывать от имени этой учётки. Не знаю правда как, но должен быть способ.

Comment: я пытаюсь спрятать от пользователей аудио файлы

Comment: Если файлы на машине юзера, то он, если захочет, получит к ним доступ.

Comment: Еще в .net есть такая штука https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx . Сам никогда не пользовался и как оно физически хранит не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, что автору необходимо спрятать используемые программой файлы от юзера. Известные мне варианты решения:

1. Шифруйте. Но это не защищает от удаления.
2. Добавить файл в ресурсы приложения. (наиболее подходящий вариант, если файлы не большие по размеру)

Comment: 3. Хранить в C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\AppName

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin как вариант, если требуется "защита от дурака". Доступ в эту папку ничем не ограничен для юзера.

Comment: она по умолчанию скрытая, так что хоть какая-то защита, у нас в одном проекте *.dll кидают в С:\Windows\SysWOW64\  как раз таки с целью спрятать

Comment: извиняюсь а что за каналы , можно поподробнее ?

Comment: а еще вопрос как правильно скрыть файлы ?
к примеру такой код скрывает файлы
`DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;`
но полностью скрыть файл он не может, при переносе программы на флэшку к примеру и если запустить прогу оттуда то файл появляется как видимый

Comment: @SamatYeshernkulov должны быть опции копирования с сохранением атрибутов.

Answer (score 0):

Спрятать данные в стримы (File streams). В виндовсе к файлу можно прицепить стримы, даже наличие которых обычными средствами (проводник) не увидеть. Создать стрим на exe-файле программы. Фиг кто догадается.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx

Правда не понятно как распространять такую прогу. Стримы наверное и не копируются обычными средствами?

Для аудио и для прочих статичных данных самое место в ресурсах, как уже кто-то ответил. Ресурсы находятся прямо в файле программы (или библиотеки).